# Brew search slow on wired connection

Tags: homebrew

Mac connected via ethernet `brew search package` takes a few minutes, the same mac connected via wifi `brew search package` takes a second or two.

This is the only difference, but really annoying. Everything else works the same on the wired and wireless connection, even speed is the same. So this is very specific problem to Homebrew.

Tested on two other macs connected to the very same cable and brew works super fast. It is clean macOS install. Any help appreciated :- )

Comment: With the given information it's almost impossible to answer such a question. Missing details: ping/traceroute to github.com and api.github.com using the two different interfaces, system version, maybe routing table.

Comment: Is there a proxy configured somewhere?